# busybox v1.22.1 multicall binary error on copy command in GitLab

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci, busybox

I am trying to copy files as part of GitLab pipeline but I am getting
`busybox v1.22.1 multicall binary error on copy command`. It was working earlier but suddently showing this error.

Here is my script

```
script:
- mkdir -p ./input
- git log -m -2 --name-only --diff-filter=d --pretty="format:"  > 
  ./input/changes.lst
- | 
   file="./input/changes.lst"
   while IFS= read -r line
   do
     printf '%s\n' "$line";
       if [ -e $line ]
       then

       `cp -R $line  ./input/`;
       fi
   done  < "$file"
only:
  - master
artifacts:
when: always
paths:
  - input
```

Comment: `cp -R $line  ./input/`;` Are you executing `cp` output?? I would suggest saving the script into a file and calling that file from gitlab-ci.

Comment: Yes, I am executing this in linux script. Multiple people work on the project, if I put it in a file everybody needs to source control this which I do not want.

Comment: Ok, but why `cp` is inside \` \` ?

Comment: Just to recognize as linux command. I tried without `` also, but did not work..

Comment: \` are used to get the output of a command, just like `$( ... )`. \`echo echo 123\` would execute `echo echo 123` then `echo 123` and will print just 123. Can you remove the \` and run it? `cp` is a linux command as it is, no need for \`. You should however put qoutes around variables in `[ -e "$line" ]` and `cp -R "$line" ./input`. What happens if you try something like `<./input/changes.lst xargs -n1 sh -c '[ -e "$1" ] && echo "$1"' -- | xargs -t -i cp -R {} /tmp` ?

Comment: Also I think you need `;` after `if` and after `while` and after `done` and after `fi`. I think gitlab-ci interprets this as a long one line (I never used `|` in gitlab-ci, not sure), so maybe try `file=... ; while IFS= read -r line; do ... if [ -e "$line" ] ; then cp ... ; fi ; done <"$file" ; `

Comment: What image are you using? I couldn't find a busybox:v1.22.1 image on docker hub.

Comment: Thank you so much Kamil Cuk. It worked after adding `;` at the end of statements. As you mentioned, it is interpreting as a one line. So, it might not be able to interpret properly.                                                                                               You can post this as an answer also, I will accept it. :-)